# Can I trust a full glmer model that converges ONLY with bobyqa and with contrast sum coding?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4

I am using R 3.2.0 with lme4 version 1.1.8. to run a mixed effects logistic regression model on some binomial data (coded as 0 and 1) from a psycholinguistic experiment. There are 2 categorical predictors (one with 2 levels and one with 3 levels) and two random terms (participants and items). I am using sum coding for the predictors (i.e. contr.sum..) which gives me the effects and interactions that I am interested in.

I find that the full model (with fixed effects and interactions, plus random intercepts AND slopes for the two random terms) converges ONLY when I specify (optimizer="bobyqa"). If I do not specify the optimizer, the model converges only after simplifying the model drastically. The same thing happens when I use the default treatment coding, even when I specify optimizer="bobyqa".

My first question is why is this happening and can I trust the output of the full model?

My second question is whether this might be due to the fact that my data is not fully balanced, in the sense that my conditions do not have exactly the same number of observations. Are there special precautions one must take when the data is not full balanced? Can one suggest any reading on this particular case?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `?convergence` help page of *more recent* versions of `lme4` (or you can read it [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/man/convergence.Rd)).  If the two fits using different optimizers give similar estimated parameters (despite one giving convergence warnings and the other not), and the fits with different contrasts give the same log-likelihood, then you probably have a reasonable fit.

In general lack of balance lowers statistical power and makes fitting more difficult, but mildly to moderate unbalanced data should present no particular problems.